# Yii Caching main layout file with beginCache/endCache

Tags: php, caching, yii

In Yii i've the main layout and the $content having changing so i do not need to cache it.
My idea is to cache `main layout`file (parts that wrap up $content, coming from `view` files):

```
 <? 
 $id= 'something';
 if($this->beginCache($id, array('duration'=>3600, 'variations' =>array(Yii::$app->language)))) {  ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head> 
 ... 
 <?php $this->endCache(); } // end of the upper cache piece ?>

     <?php echo $content; ?>

 <?php if($this->beginCache($id, array('duration'=>3600))) { // new cashe piece ?>              
        ... 
 </body>
 </html>
 <?php $this->endCache(); } ?>
```

Settings:

**config/main.php**

```
'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
            //  'connectionID'=>'db',
            //  'autoCreateCacheTable'=>false,
            //  'cacheTableName'=>'cache',
    ),
    'memcache'=>array(
       'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
     ),
```

I've put cache filters() into the main controller:

**components/Controller.php**

```
class Controller extends CController
{
   public function filters()
   {
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
        array(
            'COutputCache',
            'duration'=>1000,
            'varyByParam'=>array('id'),
        ),
     );
  }
```

I'm not sure if i do it right way. My concern also is about `$id` - what kind it should be?
After some testing i found not a big performance increase...
Would you comment/correct me?

Answer (score 0):

Your Configuration file seems to be wrong. You have enabled 2 Cachings? CFileCache and CMemCache?

Look at the reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview

The correct configuration should be:

`'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
    ),`

Comment: it is perfectly allowable to have 2 caching components in your configuration. Most built in functionality will just use the one named "cache". That doesn't have to stop you if you need a second one.